# Are USB Ethernet adapter slower than embedded NIC?

Tags: usb, lan, ethernet, network-adapter

I've just bought an usb-lan adapter.
it is usb 2.0 and 10/100Mb

it connects in full duplex at 100Mb but it is really slow: it goes 10Mb

Compared with embedded NIC same file transfert goes ~100Mb

Is it normal?

Comment: dunno though usb2 is max 480Mbps (60MB/s).  In 10/100 100 would be 100Mbps(not MB) so 12.5MB/s I guess my downloads are never more than 12.5MB/s then.  Perhaps you're confusing Mb and MB. BTW it's possible USB is slower though perhaps not affecting downloads so much maybe more in response, maybe,  and even if so, then it's probably not the cause of what you see. it may be confusiong over MB and Mb.

Comment: @barlop not confusing: B is byte, b is bit. Just a typo

Comment: That is a heck of a mistake you made - and to call it "just a typo".

Comment: @barlop it is a typo because i did it only in 1 point. check the question history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved thanks to [UsbView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) software.

Despite it is marked as usb 2 lan adatper. It is an usb 1.1 adapter

Comment: This was the case in my situation as well. The adapter I was using was marked 10/100 Mbps and USB 2.0 but USBView revealed at as a "Full" speed USB device: USB 1.1 at 12 Mbps. I'll be getting a refund from the online seller I received it from.

Answer (score 2):

As a possibility - the USB device may be 10/100 and connecting at 100 which is the speed of its connection to the wire, and it may be USB 2.0 compliant, but - what is the speed of the actual port you are connecting it to?  USB 1.1 ports are limited to 12Mb.

Comment: USB 1.0 is 1.5 Mbit/sec, USB 1.1 is 12 Mbit/sec.

Comment: It is an USB 2.0 port.